# Why my generated button from jquery doesn't have an event?

Tags: jquery

Why my generated button from jquery doesn't have an event?

```
<input type='button' value='Populate' id='pop'/>
<input type='button' value='Click' id='btn'/>
```

```
$('#pop').on('click', function(){
   var clone = $('input[id*=btn]').clone();
   $(this).after(clone);
});

$('#btn').on('click', function(){
   alert('clicked'); 
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgajo/rvhhv8sf/)

Comment: You need to understand [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the cloned button *after* you have applied event listeners. When you clone() an element *ONLY* the DOM structure is cloned, the events are not.

Either user [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) or simply pass `true` to the `clone()` function to have it clone the events also (as per [the spec](http://api.jquery.com/clone/))

```
$('#pop').on('click', function(){
   var clone = $('input[id*=btn]').clone(true); // < pass true here
   $(this).after(clone);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rvhhv8sf/3/

P.S. Id's must be unique ;)

Answer (score 2):

Id's should be unique. So changed your id `btn` to class. Use [`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).  Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.btn', function(){
   alert('clicked'); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/rvhhv8sf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating id's which is wrong just duplicate class instead.

```
<input type='button' value='Populate' id='pop'/>
<input type='button' value='Click' id='btn' class="btn"/>


$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
  alert('clicked'); 
});
```

Try this(as per your question) :

```
$(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
  alert('clicked'); 
});
```

**EDIT :**

Fiddle link :- http://jsfiddle.net/nLkvejss/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).on('click', "#btn", function(){
   alert('clicked'); 
});
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.