# HTML element created with jQuery doesn't have an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a button with the class ".test-class" that when is clicked, a checkbox is created and the message "Clicked" is shown on the console. This works great.

The checkbox must have the **same event handler**. But I click on the checkbox and the console doesn't show anything. It is like the checkbox doesn't have an event.

This is jQuery Code:

```
$(".test-class").on("click", function() {
    console.log('Clicked.');
    $("#myDiv").empty().append('<input type=checkbox class=test-class>');
});
```

This is the **button** and the **div**:

```
<button type="button" class="test-class">Click me</button>
<div id="myDiv">
    <!-- Here will appear a new checkbox. -->
</div>
```

The Developer's Tool shows the **elements**:

```
<button type="button" class="test-class">Click me</button>
<div id="mydiv">
    <input type="checkbox" class="test-class">
</div>
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564648/why-my-generated-button-from-jquery-doesnt-have-an-event) is a bit similar.

Comment: Use Kartikeya Khosla's answer to that question, not the accepted answer. Bind the event to the document and reference your dynamically created element. That should solve your issue.

Comment: Check this, you will figure rest by yourself. Also I would advise you to create elements like this in my example in future and bind whatever functions you need to them: http://jsfiddle.net/pegla/rvhhv8sf/7/